# Java EE Query two tables

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jboss

So here is my problem:
I have two tables: User and Book, they are in ManyToOne relation. The `Book` table has attribute called `user_id` that connects both tables. 
Using Eclipse I generated entity classes and work on them without problem until now.
The problem is, when I want to get "books" that have speciffic `user_id` I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [model.User (n/a)]
```

The "value" is an id that I'm getting from session, I tried it in both int and String.

**part of BookDao:**

```
public List<Book> getFullListWithId(Integer id) {
    List<Book> list = null;
    Query query = em.createQuery("select b from Book b WHERE b.user = :id");
    if (id!= null) {    
        query.setParameter("id", id);           
    }
    try {
        list = query.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

**part of BookBB:**

```
    public List<Book> getFullListWithId(){
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    Integer str =(Integer)session.getAttribute("userId");
    return  bookDAO.getFullListWithId(str);
}
```

**part of Book.java**

```
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_offer")
private int idOffer;

private String adress;

private String contact;

@Column(name="is_ready")
private String isReady;

private String name;

private String others;

private int price;

private int rooms;

private String size;

private String surname;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to User
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;
```

**part of User.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_user")
private int idUser;

private String login;

private String password;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Book
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private List<Book> books;
```

Thank you so much for any help possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

1) you pass an User object with the id as a parameter to the query (I prefer that solution):

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select b from Book b WHERE b.user = :user"); 
User u = new User();
u.setId(id)
query.setParameter("user", u);
```

2) you pass the id as a parameter:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select b from Book b WHERE b.user.id = :id");
if (id!= null) {    
     query.setParameter("id", id);           
}
```

Please note the `b.user.id` in the query

Answer (score 0):

I believe query should be `select b from Book b WHERE b.user.idUser = :id`

You might want to take a look at hibernate docs

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html {Chapter 16}

Comment: Thank you too man, i would deffinetly check the documentation. One more time: thank you!